# SQL shortest query to count unique users

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following data base:

```
    Table users: 
-  user_id VARCHAR *primary key 
-  registration_date DATE 
-  last_active_date DATE 
-  country VARCHAR 
-  is_subscriber BOOLEAN  
    
    Table activity: 
-  activity_id VARCHAR *primary key 
-  activity_date DATE 
-  activity_name VARCHAR 
-  user_id VARCHAR  
    
    Table object_info: 
-  object_id VARCHAR *primary key 
-  object_name VARCHAR 
-  object_cost FLOAT 
-  is_discount BOOLEAN
    
    Table transactions: 
-  transaction_id VARCHAR *primary key 
-  transaction_date DATE 
-  object_id VARCHAR *references object_information.objectt_id 
-  user_id VARCHAR *references users.user_id
```

I want to write a query that counts the number of unique users buying a chair (object_name = chair) on 2020-08-12. I thought it should be something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(object_name),user_id
FROM object_info
GROUP BY user_id;
```

It doesn't include the date and it doesn't seem to be the shortest possible query. How else could I do it?

Comment: Mysql and sqlite are two different rdbms products with different implementations of sql. I removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use (I suspect it will be mysql)

Comment: not sure what you mean by "shortest"; can you explain why you are looking for the shortest query?  what benefit do you expect from a shorter query over a "longer" equivalent one?

Comment: @ysth I meant in terms of number of characters, spaces and comments not included. I was thinking that there must be something different and more efficient than using join and count(distinct).

Comment: number of characters and effiency are two very different things.  and readability and maintainability are more important than even efficiency, unless you have specific efficiency requirements that need to be met.

Comment: @johnnydoe there is nothing else than `count(distinct ...)` that counts distinct instances.

Comment: @forpas there's `select count(*) from (select user_id ... group by 1)x`; but that's just more obfuscated and not any shorter

Comment: @ysth would you ever use it instead of `count(distinct...)`?

Comment: @forpas you wouldn't :) but it is something else that counts distinct instances

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like `join`s and `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.user_id)
FROM transactions t JOIN
     object_info oi
     ON t.object_id = oi.object_id
WHERE oi.object_name = 'chair';
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 tables involved: `transactions` and `object_info` so you must join them to get the object's name and then aggregate:

```
select count(distinct t.user_id) counter
from transactions t inner join object_info o
on o.object_id = t.object_id
where t.transaction_date = '2020-08-12' and o.object_name = 'chair'
```